# How to update the details after filling a form in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

I have a database consisting info about celebrities. The info of different celebrities are shown in different accordions. Every accordion has an edit button, which opens a form to edit the different info fields present inside the accordion.

I am not able to save and reflect those inputs entered in the form.

Whenever I try to save the details, I am encountering the following error in `AccordionForm.jsx`:

> id.findIndex is not a function

I think I am not able to get the id from the database.

Home.jsx

```
return (
  <div>
    <div className="app_header">
      <p>Celebrities Wiki List</p>
    </div>

    {data.map(
      ({ id, first, last, dob, gender, picture, country, description }) => (
        <Accordion
          key={id}
          id={id}
          first={first}
          last={last}
          dob={dob}
          gender={gender}
          picture={picture}
          country={country}
          description={description}
        />
      ),
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Accordion.jsx

```
const Accordion = (props) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState(false);

  const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="accordion-container">
      <div className="accordion-item">
        <div className="accordion-title" onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}>
          <div className="accordion-head">
            <img src={props.picture} alt="celebrity-img" />
            <div className="name">
              {props.first} {props.last}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            {isActive ? (
              <SlArrowUp fontSize={20} color="#a4a597" cursor={"pointer"} />
            ) : (
              <SlArrowDown fontSize={20} color="#a4a597" cursor={"pointer"} />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>

        {showModal ? (
          <AccordionForm
            id={props.id}
            age={props.age}
            gender={props.gender}
            country={props.country}
            description={props.description}
            updateAccordion={props.updateAccordion}
            onClose={() => setShowModal(false)}
          />
        ) : (
          <>
            {isActive && (
              <div className="accordion-body">
                <div className="accordion-info">
                  <div className="age">
                    <p className="info-tag">Age</p>
                    <p className="content-text">{props.dob} Years</p>
                  </div>

                  <div className="gender">
                    <p className="info-tag">Gender</p>
                    <p className="content-text">{props.gender}</p>
                  </div>

                  <div className="country">
                    <p className="info-tag">Country</p>
                    <p className="content-text">{props.country}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className="accordion-content">
                  <p className="info-tag">Description</p>
                  <p className="content-text">{props.description}</p>
                </div>

                <div className="accordion-buttons">
                  <BsTrash3 fontSize={20} color="red" cursor={"pointer"} />
                  <BsPencil
                    fontSize={20}
                    color="blue"
                    cursor={"pointer"}
                    onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

AccordionForm.jsx

```
const AccordionForm = (props) => {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({ ...props });

  const updateAccordion = (id) => {
    const index = id.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
    if (index < 0) return;
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (
      values.id === props.id &&
      values.first === props.first &&
      values.last === props.last &&
      values.description === props.description &&
      values.country === props.country &&
      values.age === props.age &&
      values.gender === props.gender
    )
      return;

    updateAccordion(props.id, values);
  }, [values]);

  return (
    <Modal onClose={() => props.onClose()}>
      <div className="accordion-body">
        <div className="accordion-info">
          <div className="age">
            <p className="info-tag">Age</p>

            <Editable
              text={values.age}
              default={values.age}
              placeholder="Enter Age"
              onSubmit={(value) => setValues({ ...values, age: value })}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="gender">
            <p className="info-tag">Gender</p>

            <Editable
              text={values.gender}
              default={values.gender}
              placeholder="State Your Gender"
              onSubmit={(value) => setValues({ ...values, gender: value })}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="country">
            <p className="info-tag">Country</p>

            <Editable
              text={values.country}
              default={values.country}
              placeholder="Enter Country"
              onSubmit={(value) => setValues({ ...values, country: value })}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="accordion-content">
          <p className="info-tag">Description</p>

          <Editable
            name={values.description}
            default={values.description}
            placeholder="Enter Description"
            onSubmit={(value) => setValues({ ...values, description: value })}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="accordion-buttons">
          <button type="submit">
            <img className="form-check" type src={check} alt="save" />
          </button>

          <button>
            <img
              className="form-cross"
              src={cross}
              alt="close"
              onClick={() => props.onClose()}
            />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Modal.jsx

```
const Modal = (props) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="modal"
      onClick={() => (props.onClose ? props.onClose() : "")}
    >
      <div
        className="modal_content"
        onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
      >
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Why are you not able to save?  Are you encountering an error?  Please give more details about what is or is not happening.

Comment: @dmikester1 I have edited my question. Hopefully someone will be able to provide me a suitable answer

Comment: You would call `findIndex` on an array.  But I am assuming `id` is not an array, but likely an int(number)?

Comment: The `updateAccordion` function does not look finished.  What exactly are you trying to do in there?

Comment: @dmikester1 yes 'id' is an int. 
updateAccordion would save the new inputs from the form and update the info present inside the accordion. I'm not able to retrieve the id from the database to the updateAccordion function.

Comment: If id is an int, you cannot call `findIndex` on it, because it is not an array.  Like I said, that function does not appear to be finished because you are not doing anything if `id >= 0`.